Storing and retrieving encrypted data using Entity Framework not working as expected
I'm trying to store and retrieve encrypted data using Entity Framework with the following configuration. However, it seems that the data isn't being stored in the encrypted form as intended.
Here's my code:
public class Encrptconfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Lrb.Domain.Entities.DataEncryption>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Lrb.Domain.Entities.DataEncryption> builder)
    {
        builder.IsMultiTenant();
        builder.Property(e => e.Name)
            .IsEncrypted(SoftFluent.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StorageFormat.Base64)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}

public class DataEncryption : AuditableEntity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : BaseDbContext
{
    private readonly IEncryptionProvider _provider;

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        var encryptionKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("TGVhZHJhdA==");
        var encryptionIvBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("TGVhZHJhdA==");

        _provider = new AesProvider(encryptionKeyBytes, encryptionIvBytes);
    }

    public DbSet<DataEncryption> DataEncryption => Set<DataEncryption>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseEncryption(_provider);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

Issue: I expect that when I save data to the DataEncryption table, the Name property should be stored in an encrypted format, and when I retrieve it, I should get the decrypted value. However, this isn't happening.
Does anyone know what could be going wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

there is no UseEncryption method for ModelBuilder defined in well knowned libs (part of the framework or done by microsoft)

@Selvin I'd guess its about UseEncryption from
EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption Nuget-Package

I want to store the data in the Database in the form of Encrypted while getting i need to get the data in the form of the decrypted form

@BharatiHattikal And what happens instead?

it was storing  decrypted format only

There's no official EntityFrameworkCore.DataEncryption NuGet package. The only match in NuGet is an obscure package abandoned since 2022 with just 2K downloads. You can't just throw "encryption" at a problem anyway. You have to think what you're protecting against. Databases and database drivers already offers solutions for specific problems. The SSL/TLS encryption provided by database drivers is far better at protecting against eavesdropping at the connection level. Database-level encryption protects against disk theft and. SQL Server's Always Encrypted prevents even DBAs from reading data

But i need to store the data in the form of encrypted form only is there any ways to encryptions

hello please help me to resolve this is there any ways to resolve this?

How are you checking whether the data is encrypted or decrypted?

while creating the data it is stored in database with encrypted format and for getting i wrote endpoint to get that encrypted data
